# Failure to create a monitor with mutex and condition_variable in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, monitor, condition-variable

I am trying to create a monitor class to get sum of data[]. In the class, I use a monitor a do the reading/writer working. However, the condition_variable, `unique_lock` and `mutex` confuse me. When the data size is not over 56, my code works correctly but with a bigger data size the code fails, and the `condition_variable.wait(cond_lock)` cannot work when debugging in lldb.

> The error:  type std::__1::system_error: unique_lock::unlock: not locked:
> Operation not permitted

does not help me to understand the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

const int datasize = 58;//*****datasize cannot be bigger than 56*****//
int *data = new int[datasize];

void data_init(){
    for (int i = 0; i < datasize; ++i) {
        data[i] = random() % datasize + 1;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < datasize; ++i) {
        sum += data[i];
    }
    std::cout << "true answer: " << sum << std::endl;
}
class monitor{
public:
    std::mutex the_mutex;//the mutex to lock the function
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> cond_mutex;//trying to use this for condition_variable
    std::condition_variable read_to_go, write_to_go;
    int active_reader, active_writer, waiting_reader, waiting_writer;
    bool write_flag;
    void getTask(int Rank, int& task_one, int& task_two, int& second_rank);//**reader**//
    void putResult(int Rank, int the_answer, int next_Rank);//**writer**//
    explicit monitor(){
        write_flag = true;
        active_reader = active_writer = waiting_reader = waiting_writer = 0;
    }
private:
    inline void startRead();
    inline void endRead();
    inline void startWrite();
    inline void endWrite();
};

monitor imonitor;

inline void monitor::startRead() {
    the_mutex.lock();//lock the function code
    cond_mutex.lock();//updated 1st
    while((active_writer + active_reader) > 0){//if there are working reader and writer
        waiting_reader++;//add one 
        read_to_go.wait(cond_mutex);//wait the thread
        /*****when debugging with lldb, error appears here*****/
        waiting_reader--;//one less reader waiting when notified
    }
    active_reader++;//one more working reader
    the_mutex.unlock();
}

inline void monitor::endRead() {
    the_mutex.lock();
    active_reader--;//one less reader working
    if(active_reader == 0 && waiting_writer > 0){//if there is not any reader working and there are some writer waiting
        write_to_go.notify_one();//notify one writer
    }//else get out directly
    the_mutex.unlock();
}

inline void monitor::startWrite() {
    the_mutex.lock();
    cond_mutex.lock();//updated 1st
    while((active_writer + active_reader) > 0){//if any reader or writer is working
        waiting_writer++;//one more writer waiting
        write_to_go.wait(cond_mutex);//block this thread
        waiting_writer--;//when notfied, the number of waiting writer become less
    }
    active_writer++;//one more active writer
    the_mutex.unlock();//updated 1st
}

inline void monitor::endWrite() {//write is over
    the_mutex.lock();
    active_writer--;//one less writer working
    if(waiting_writer > 0){//if any writer waiting
        write_to_go.notify_one();//notify one of them
    }
    else if(waiting_reader > 0){//if any reader waiting
        read_to_go.notify_all();//notify all of them
    }
    the_mutex.unlock();
}

void monitor::getTask(int Rank, int &task_one, int &task_two, int &second_rank) {
    startRead();
    task_one = data[Rank];
    while(Rank < (datasize - 1) && data[++Rank] == 0);
    task_two = data[Rank];
    second_rank = Rank;
    //std::cout << "the second Rank is " << Rank << std::endl;
    endRead();
}

void monitor::putResult(int Rank, int the_answer, int next_Rank) {
    startWrite();
    data[Rank] = the_answer;
    data[next_Rank] = 0;
    endWrite();
}

void reducer(int Rank){
    //std::cout << "a reducer begins" << Rank << std::endl;
    do {
        int myTask1, myTask2, secondRank;
        imonitor.getTask(Rank, myTask1, myTask2, secondRank);
        if(myTask2 == 0) return;
        //std::cout << "the second value Rank: " << secondRank << std::endl;
        int answer = myTask1 + myTask2;
        imonitor.putResult(Rank, answer, secondRank);
    }while (true);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    data_init();

    std::thread Reduce1(reducer, 0);
    std::thread Reduce2(reducer, datasize/2);
    /*std::thread Reduce3(reducer, 4);
    std::thread Reduce4(reducer, 6);
    std::thread Reduce5(reducer, 8);
    std::thread Reduce6(reducer, 10);
    std::thread Reduce7(reducer, 12);
    std::thread Reduce8(reducer, 14);*/

    Reduce1.join(); //std::cout << "A reducer in" <<std::endl;
    Reduce2.join();
    /*Reduce3.join();
    Reduce4.join();
    Reduce5.join();
    Reduce6.join();
    Reduce7.join();
    Reduce8.join();*/

    std::cout << data[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My goal used to use 8 threads, but now the code can work with only one thread. Some `cout` for debugging are left in the code. Thank you for any help!
Updated 1st: I add `cond_mutex.lock()` in `startWrite()` and `startRead()` after `the_mutex.lock()`. The error in the last line of `startWrite` about `cond_mutex.unlock()` is fixed, which is replaced by `the_mutex.unlock()`. However, the problem is not fixed.

Comment: In `startWrite()` you lock `the_mutex` but you unlock `cond_mutex`.

Comment: At the first line of  **startWrite()**, I lock **the_mutex** and unlock it at the last line. Do you mean I do not unlock **the_mutex** in `read_to_go.wait(cond_mutex)` ?

Comment: You do not unlock `the_mutex` at the last line of `startWrite()`, you unlock `cond_mutex` instead.

Comment: where unique_lock should have been locked before `.wait()`

Comment: OK, I find it. Thank you very much. Now, I do believe my eyes need relax.

Comment: The problem is not fixed. :(

Answer (score 0):

OK, guys. Thanking for your comments, I am inspired to work this problem out.

1. At the very beginning, I used `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> cond_mutex;` in the declaration of the monitor class, meaning the default initializer of **unique_lock** is called.

   `class monitor{ public: std::mutex the_mutex, assist_lock;/***NOTE HERE***/ std::unique_lock<std::mutex> cond_mutex;/***NOTE HERE***/ std::condition_variable read_to_go, write_to_go; int active_reader, active_writer, waiting_reader, waiting_writer; ...... };`
2. Let us check the header **__mutex_base**, where the **mutex** and **unique_lock** are defined.(begin at line 104)

   `template 
   class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS unique_lock
   {
   public:
   typedef _Mutex mutex_type;

   private:
   mutex_type* _*m*;
   bool _*owns*;

   public:
   _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
   unique_lock() _NOEXCEPT : _*m*(nullptr), _*owns*(false) {}/***first and default***/
   _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
   explicit unique_lock(mutex_type& __m)
   : _*m*(_VSTD::addressof(__m)), _*owns*(true) {_*m*->lock();}/***second and own an object***/
   ......
   };`

   Obviously, the first initializer is used instead of second one. `__m_` is `nullptr`.
3. When the `<condition_variable>.wait(cond_mutex);` call the `lock()`, we will find the error information: `"unique_lock::lock: references null mutex"`(in the header **__mutex_base**, line 207).
4. When `<unique_lock>.unlock()` called, because the `lock()` does not work the **bool** `__owns_` is **false**(line 116&211), we will get error information: `"unique_lock::unlock: not locked"`(line 257).

To fix the problem, we cannot use an all-covered `unique_lock cond_mutex`, but to initialize `cond_mutex` each time we want to use `startRead()` and `endStart()` with an object `the_mutex`. In this way, the `<unique_lock> cond_mutex(the_mutex)` is initialized by the second initializer function, at the same time `the_mutex` is locked and `<unique_lock> cond_mutex` owns `the_mutex`. At the end of
`startRead()` and `endStart()`, `cond_mutex.unlock()` unlocks itself and `the_mutex`, then the `cond_mutex` dies and releases `the_mutex`.

```
class monitor{
public:
std::mutex the_mutex;
std::condition_variable read_to_go, write_to_go;
int active_reader, active_writer, waiting_reader, waiting_writer;
bool write_flag;
void getTask(int Rank, int& task_one, int& task_two, int& second_rank);//reader
void putResult(int Rank, int the_answer, int next_Rank);//writer
explicit monitor(){
    write_flag = true;
    active_reader = active_writer = waiting_reader = waiting_writer = 0;
}
private:
inline void startRead();
inline void endRead();
inline void startWrite();
inline void endWrite();
};

inline void monitor::startRead() {
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> cond_mutex(the_mutex);
while((active_writer + active_reader) > 0){
    waiting_reader++;
    read_to_go.wait(cond_mutex);
    waiting_reader--;
}
active_reader++;
cond_mutex.unlock();
}

inline void monitor::startWrite() {
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> cond_mutex(the_mutex);
while((active_writer + active_reader) > 0){
    waiting_writer++;
    write_to_go.wait(cond_mutex);
    waiting_writer--;
}
active_writer++;
cond_mutex.unlock();
```

}

The solution is here, just to replace my a part of original code with the code above.  After all, thank everyone who gives comments.

Comment: Stop manually unlocking the mutex.  Use scope.  Use the "lambda" overload of wait instead of your manual loop.  `++waiting_blah; cv.wait(lock, [&]{ return !active_read && !active_write; } ); --waiting_blah;`

Comment: I saw your answer, thanks for it very much. I am a beginner and have no idea about lambda for now. :)@Takk - Adam Nevraumont

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be writing this:

```
class write_wins_mutex {
  std::condition_variable cv_read;
  std::condition_variable cv_write;
  std::mutex m;
  int readers=0;
  int writers=0;
  int waiting_writers=0;
  int waiting_readers=0;
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> internal_lock(){ return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>( m );
public:
  void shared_lock() {
    auto l = internal_lock();
    ++waiting_readers;
    cv_read.wait(l, [&]{ return !readers && !writers && !waiting_writers; } );
    --waiting_readers;
    ++readers;
  }
  void lock() {
    auto l = internal_lock();
    ++waiting_writers;
    cv_write.wait(l, [&]{ return !readers && !writers; } );
    --waiting_writers;
    ++writers;
  }
private:
  void notify(){
    if (waiting_writers) {
      if(!readers) cv_write.notity_one();
    }
    else if (waiting_readers) cv_read.notify_all();
  }
public:
  void unlock_shared(){
    auto l = internal_lock();
    --readers;
    notify();
  }
  void unlock(){
    auto l = internal_lock();
    --writers;
    notify();
  }
};
```

probably has typos; wrote this on phone without compiling it.

But this is a mutex compatible with shared_lock and unique_lock (no try lock (for) but that just means those methods don't work).

In this model, readers are shared, but if any writer shows up it gets priority (even to the level of being able to starve readers)

If you want something less biased, just use shared mutex directly.